# Я могу как-то воспользоваться совместно FindAsync и Include?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-core

В общем, есть Generic-метод, который по ключу возвращает сущность:

```
`await context.Set<T>().FindAsync(key, token)`
```

, а снаружи принимает id, который является типом object, который я привожу в коде к ключу:

```
var key = id is object[] objects ? objects : new[] {id};
```

Эта штука работает, но проблема в том, что мне теперь понадобилось так же подгружаться данные к этой сущности через навигационные свойства.

Когда я добавляю Include, то я теряю возможность пользоваться удобным для себя FindAsync.

Через `context.Entry(T).Reference()`- это, вроде, геморнее делается, если мне еще потребуется идти в глубь, а в Include, как я понимаю, такой проблемы нет.

Какие есть решения проблемы?

Comment: Я могу конечно просить снаружи condition, но это слишком громоздко... Мысля пришла с кондишинами побаловаться

Comment: нельзя сделать 2 метода? Один `FindAsync<T>(){db.Set<T>()...}`, другой ``FindAsync<MyDmainType>(){db.Set<MyDmainType>().Incluse(...)...}`` ?

Comment: @tym32167 немного не понял.

Comment: Просто предложил не менять метод, который у вас для общего случая, а добавить отдельный метод для вашей сущности.

Comment: @tym32167 но мне может быть неизвестны заранее сущности...

Comment: Значит я не так понял ваш вопрос :)

Answer (score 0):

В общем, сделал так:

Метод, который по некоторой конфигурации "обогащает" набор данных `Include`:

```
public IQueryable<T> Ecrich<T>(DbSet<T> dbSet) where T : class
{
    var config = _navPropLoaderProfile.NavigationDictionary[typeof(T)];
    var query = dbSet.AsQueryable();
    return config.NavPropNames.Aggregate(query, (current, nav) => current.Include(nav));
}
```

Методы которыми я генерю условие и получаю желаемый результат:

```
public async Task<T> GetOldObjectAsync<T>(T entity, CancellationToken token = default) where T : class
{

    using (var context = _contextFactory.Create())
    {
        var key = GetKey<T>(context);
        return await _navPropEnrichService.Ecrich(context.Set<T>()).FirstOrDefaultAsync(BuildCondition(key, entity), token);
    }
}

private IEnumerable<PropertyInfo> GetKey<T>(DbContext context)
{
    return context.Model.FindEntityType(typeof(T)).FindPrimaryKey().Properties.Select(x => x.PropertyInfo);
}

private Expression<Func<T, bool>> BuildCondition<T>(IEnumerable<PropertyInfo> keyProps, T entity)
{
    var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T));
    Expression cond = null;
    foreach (var prop in keyProps)
    {
        var equalExpr = Expression.Equal(Expression.Property(param, prop), Expression.Constant(prop.GetValue(entity)));
        cond = cond == null ? equalExpr : Expression.And(cond, equalExpr);
    }
    return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(cond, param);
}
```

Критика и рекомендации приветствуются.